# , Drop column Error ora-00933 sql command not properly ended

Tags: oracle12c, toad, alter-table

I need to drop an column in my existing table. Not sure why below syntax is not working for me and getting  '**ora-00933 sql command not properly ended**'

DB Query:

```
ALTER TABLE employee DROP COLUMN  TITLE;
```

Please suggest. Using oracle 12c version.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the SQL query you used. Are you executing this query from Java or any other language? If thats the case, you need to remove semi-colon at the end of the query.

Comment: I am using Toad IDE to execute the query. any thoughts what I am missing here?

Comment: I tried with removing semi-colon and it worked  out. Not why this was causing the issue. Weird behavior..

Comment: What version of Toad are you on and how are you executing your statement in the Editor? There are multiple ways to execute and Toad should be handling the semicolon automatically behind the scenes. I tested F9, Ctrl+Enter, and Shift+F9 to execute in every commercially available release since 12.1 and cannot reproduce; however, this sounds vaguely familiar as having come up before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @learningloop for suggestions.

I tried after removing the semi-colon in the SQL and it worked out. I was using toad editor for the query execution.